# VSCode Debug Console Colour change

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've found [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) on how to add all sorts of weird and wonderful colours to my vscode terminal as well as the text (and only the text) of the vscode debug console.

What I'd like to know is how to change the BACKGROUND colour of the debug console that is integrated with vscode. The reason for this is because my background is black, and my highlight colour is black, meaning I can't even see if I'm actually highlighting anything.

The gif below shows my terminal (which is great) and my debug console (which is dark and difficult to see if I'm highlighting anything).

Current look in my terminal and debug console:

[image]

Current code in `settings.json`:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "debugConsole.warningForeground": "#f06a6a",
        "debugConsole.errorForeground": "#eb5a5a",
        "debugConsole.sourceForeground": "#0c0",
        "debugConsole.infoForeground": "#ececf3",
        "debugView.valueChangedHighlight": "#ececf3",
        "terminal.foreground" : "#00FD61",
        "terminal.background" : "#000000",
        "editorSuggestWidget.background": "#24262b",
        "editorSuggestWidget.selectedBackground": "#768fc4",
        "editorSuggestWidget.highlightForeground": "#ffffff",
        "editor.selectionBackground": "#805d5d",
        "editor.selectionForeground": "#ff0000"
    },
```

Comment: while switching themes, the background color changes for the different parts so there has to be a theme color for that

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a `colorCustomization` for debug background colors.

Answer (score 2):

You want `panel.background`. For instance, here is my theme customization:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
   "[CodePen-Nights]": {
     "panel.border": "#616167",
     "sideBar.border": "#616167",
     "sideBar.background": "#21222c",
     "panel.background": "#21222c", // <----- This one here
     "extensionIcon.verifiedForeground": "#47cf90",
     "sideBar.foreground": "#c4c4c0",
     "debugConsole.infoForeground": "#96b0f9",
     "terminal.foreground": "#ff0000",
     "editorLineNumber.foreground": "#47c256",
     "editorLineNumber.activeForeground": "#ff00ff"
    }
 },
```